# Can python do a gaussian fitting and extrapolation?

Tags: python, numpy

I think numpy or scipy will do it, but didn't find. Thanks!

Comment: Could you define your problem more precisely.

Answer (score 15):

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats

np.random.seed(0)
gaussian = stats.norm
```

Generating some random, normal data:

```
data = gaussian.rvs(loc = 5, scale = 22, size = 1000)
```

Computing descriptive statistics:

```
print(data.mean())
# 4.00435243522
print(data.std())
# 21.7147294907
```

Fitting the data to a normal distribution:

```
mean, std = gaussian.fit(data)
print(mean, std)
# (4.0043524352157016, 21.714729490718568)
```

Comment: Is there any way I can do extrapolation?

Comment: What do you mean by extrapolation?